# How to hover li elem color in nav navbar-nav of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I use bootstrap ui.

I have navbar in main page, and it has ul tag with nav navbar-nav class.

There are product and market li in this ul tag.

Now  product and market should  be  changed its color when mouse over.

I have trid to define with hove like:

```
<style>
active :hover{color:green}
</style>
```

But unlucky, it worked fail.

Here is my page code:

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta charset="utf-8"><title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

<link href="jsui/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/easyui-1.5.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsui/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  active :hover{color:green}
   </style>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:70px">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="pic/logo.png" style="width:130px;height:40px;margin-top:2px"></a>
</div>
<div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="visibility: visible;">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">product</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">market</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                customer <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>  
</body>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: .navbar .nav .active:hover{color:green !important}

Comment: missing a `.` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is fine, you just got something wrong about the selector in CSS.

The correct way to select "Product" and "Market" would be:

```
.navbar .nav li.active a:hover{color:green}
```

> **Just to explain the Selector:**
>
> We are looking first for the `.navbar` Class which is on the `<nav>`
>   Element.
>
> Then we give it a space (Otherwise it would try to find both Classes
>   on the same Element.
>
> After that we look for `.nav` which is a Class on the `<ul>`
>   (**Descendent** of `<nav class="navbar">`) If you would try to select
>   only a direct **Child** you would use the Child-Selector">".
>
> Last but not least, we give it a space and select every `<li>` Element
>   which has the `.active` Class (Notice that there is no space between
>   "li" and ".active")
>
> At the very end we are looking for the `<a>` Element because the Text
>   is written inside of it and give it `:hover` (No Space) which is a
>   **Pseudoclass**

[Here you can check out the working Pen](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/GxMdyY)